# Why I can't remove a subelement from xml.etree.ElementTree.Element?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I don't understand what is going on?
I have **xml.etree.ElementTree.Element** objects with the following representation:

```
<root>
   <tag1>some text</tag1>
   <l1>text</l1>
   <l2>text</l2>
</root>
```

I want to remove `<tag1>...</tag1>` subelement. **etree_collection** is an OrderedDict that contains ElementTree.Element objects.

```
   for etree in etree_collection.values():
        tag1 = etree.iter('tag1')
        etree.remove(tag1)
```

This code produces `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` error.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`etree.iter('tag1')` returns a `ElementDepthFirstIterator`:

```
In [175]: etree.iter('tag1')
Out[175]: <lxml.etree.ElementDepthFirstIterator at 0x7f43736a61e0>
```

You'd have to iterate through the items in the iterator to obtain `<tag1>` `Elements`:

```
In [176]: list(etree.iter('tag1'))
Out[176]: [<Element tag1 at 0x7f4373698ef0>]
```

Instead, you could use `find` to obtain the first `<tag1>` `Element` in `etree`:

```
In [177]: etree.find('tag1')
Out[177]: <Element tag1 at 0x7f4373698ef0>
```

---

So using `find` you might use something like:

```
for elt in etree_collection.values():
     tag1 = elt.find('tag1')
     elt.remove(tag1)
```

(I changed `etree` to `elt` since `etree` reminds me too much of the module `xml.etree`.)

---

If there can be more than one `<tag1>` `Element` in `elt`, then you could use

```
for elt in etree_collection.values():
    for tag1 in elt.iter('tag1'):
        elt.remove(tag1)
```

Comment: hmm, for some reason the exact same code does not work for me.

Comment: `elt.remove(tag1)` can remove `tag1` only if it is a direct child of `elt`.